# How to get count of matching words in R

Tags: r

I have two sentence, say

```
s1="apple is java with mango and orange"
s2="fruit is apple and orange"
```

I need to get the common words in both sentence or at least the count of it in R. In above example `apple,is,orange,and` are the words

I tried `adist`, `grep` but nothing seem to work

Comment: you could try `intersect(unlist(strsplit(s2," ")),unlist(strsplit(s1," ")))
`

Comment: `adist` and `grep` work the way they are designed for. Please read the help pages. And search for a duplicate before posting, please.